# How do I get the unique timezone name out of a moment.tz object?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

Say you have a `moment` object, initialized to some timezone, say "US/Pacific" (not necessarily the browser's time zone).  How do you get the "US/Pacific" name back out?   I can get the abbreviation or the offset, but how do I get the actual unique timezone?

```
var m = moment.tz("US/Pacific");
console.log(m.zoneAbbr());  //  "PDT"
console.log(m.zoneName());  //  "PDT"
console.log(m.format("Z"));  //  "-07:00"
console.log(m.format("ZZ"));  //  "-0700"
console.log(m.format("z"));  //  "PDT"
console.log(m.format("zz"));  //  "PDT"
```

I want to get "US/Pacific" back out, as that's the globally unique name, regardless of offset or daylight savings, or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the name of the time zone that was assigned to the moment instance using the [`tz()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) method without any arguments.

```js
const dt = moment().tz('US/Pacific');
console.log(dt.tz());
// US/Pacific
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```